# Connect to Server is ..... different / not working

Tags: server, windows, sharing

I'm trying to connect my Blackberry Playbook to U16.04 LTS. I would normally "connect to server" and from the drop down menu choose the "windows share" option. I last did this about 12 months ago.
Now, the "connect to server" option seems to be in the "files", down at the bottom, as in the screen shot below. There is no drop down menu.
So, my BB/PB will not connect to Ubuntu [or the other way around] as I don't seem to be able to make Ubuntu do "windows share" any more.

[image]

Does anyone have a clue what I am doing wrong?
Answers in long hand, please, as I am GUI person, not a terminal man.

Comment: 16.10 is not LTS. Do you mean 16.04 LTS, or 16.10, or what?

Comment: I do indeed mean 16.04 LTS. This was a typing error from my over eager fingers.....

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Now, are you trying to *set up* a share? Or connect to one?  The way your question is written, it sounds like you are on your blackberry using nautilus (aka files). Or are you trying to set up a share for your blackberry to connect to?

Comment: Hi.....I am trying to connect my BB Playbook to Ubuntu so I can swap files between them. It is not something I do often and the process goes like this : on the PB tell it to allow file share and think of windows. Connect a USB cable and note the USB IP Address.
Connect to Ubuntu, Connect to Server, select Windows Share from the drop down, add the IP address and connect.
This has worked in the past, but now Connect to Server is embedded, rather than as a dialogue box and there are no "drop down" options. I have only noticed this now as I only use this feature for my Playbook.

Comment: I have connected to my BBPB differently and am transfering files essentially via wifi. Not ideal but it is working.

However, my initial issue, not being able to connect via USB is still an issue and the "connect to server" is not working. Or is working differently to that which I was expecting. Hey Ho.